# Reading image from Belgian EID card

Tags: uwp, smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader, eid

When I am reading `EF(ID#RN`) file using APDU command from card - everything is fine.
But when I am trying to read image file `EF(ID#Photo)`, then image is cropped. I can read correctly only first 510-512 bytes.

File read operation is always returning 90-00 - success response. So, I am setting file size limited (to 3064 bytes) to stop read operation.

Have read in google group that it could be related to transactions. But my platform is UWP and transactions are not supported in `Windows.Devices.SmartCards` namespace. Can be sure that image on card is not broken (as it could be readed by third-party software).

My code is very similar to readBinary method in next one [example](https://github.com/e-Contract/commons-eid/blob/master/commons-eid-client/src/main/java/be/fedict/commons/eid/client/BeIDCard.java):

Here it is:

```
        List<byte> resultBytes = new List<byte>();
        byte offset = 0x00;
        byte size = 0xFF;

        var fileBytes = await GetBytes(card, new byte[] { 0x00, 0xB0, (byte)(offset >> 8), (byte)(offset & 0xFF), size });

        if (fileBytes[0] == 0x6C)
        {
            size = fileBytes[1];
            fileBytes = await GetBytes(card, new byte[] { 0x00, 0xB0, (byte)(offset >> 8), (byte)(offset & 0xFF), size });
        }

        while (fileBytes[fileBytes.Length - 2] == 0x90 && fileBytes[fileBytes.Length - 1] == 0x00)
        {
            if (resultBytes.Count >= maxSize && maxSize > 0) break;

            var newBytes = fileBytes.ToList();
            newBytes.RemoveRange(fileBytes.Length - 2, 2);
            resultBytes.AddRange(newBytes);

            if (maxSize > 0 && resultBytes.Count > maxSize - size) size = (byte)(maxSize - resultBytes.Count);

            offset = (byte)(offset + size);

            fileBytes = await GetBytes(card, new byte[] { 0x00, 0xB0, (byte)(offset >> 8), (byte)(offset & 0xFF), size });

            if (fileBytes[0] == 0x6C)
            {
                size = fileBytes[1];
                fileBytes = await GetBytes(card, new byte[] { 0x00, 0xB0, (byte)(offset >> 8), (byte)(offset & 0xFF), size });
            }
        }

        return resultBytes;
```

Comment: Hi, please provide the code you wrote. In the example you gave, the code language is Java.

Comment: @guidot, you absolutely right. You can add it as an answer. Offset should be of type `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, the line:

```
offset =  (byte)(offset + size)
```

is the problem. If you cast to byte, how can offset increase?